# Test fails if an Exception is thrown in another part of the SUT (async flow)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, moq

I have a system like this

```
class Sut
{
    IRepository _repo;

    public Sut(IRepository repo) { _repo = repo; }

    async Task Handle(Request request)
    {
         var entity  = new Entity(request.Id); //=> if Id is not ok the Entity throws Exception
    
         _repo.Save(entity);
    }
}
```

This is the test

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test_Save()
{
    Mock<IRepository> repositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository>();

    repositoryMock
        .Setup(repo => repo.Save(It.IsAny<Entity>()))
        .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

    var sut = new Sut(repositoryMock.Object);

    /// Act
    Action action = async () => await sut.Handle(new Request { Id = default(Guid)});

    /// Assert 
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(action);
    repositoryMock.Verify(repo => repo.Save(It.IsAny<Entity>(), Times.Never);
}
```

So what it does is, the `Entity` has a check for default `Guid` being passed to it. If default value is passed it will throw an Exception.

The exception is thrown but the test fails with this message.

> Message: Assert.Throws()
>
> Failure Expected: typeof(System.Exception)
>
> Actual:   (No exception was thrown)

The test never calls

```
repositoryMock.Verify(repo => repo.Save(It.IsAny<Entity>(), Times.Never);
```

it will break at this line

Why is that and how to solve this situation ?

```
Assert.Throws<Exception>(action);
```

**UPDATE**

```
 public Entity(Guid id)
 {
     if (default(Guid) == id) throw new Exception("cannot have a default value for id");
     Id = id;
 }
```

Comment: Are you in control of `Entity`?

Comment: Show `Entity` as it relates to the statement *`if Id is not ok the Entity throws Exception`*

Comment: Ok I think I see the problem. The `Action action` is basically an `async void`, which would mean that the thrown exception wont get caught.

Comment: I've also tried without the Action and removing the Assertion part leaving only the Verification, When I do that I get the exception **Message: Sytem.Exception : cannot have a default value for id**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Action action = async () => ...` is basically an `async void`, which would mean that the thrown exception wont get caught.

Change the syntax to use a `Func<Task>` along with `Assert.ThrowsAsync`

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test_Save() {
    //Arrange
    var repositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository>();

    repositoryMock
        .Setup(repo => repo.Save(It.IsAny<Entity>()))
        .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

    var sut = new Sut(repositoryMock.Object);

    /// Act
    AsyncTestDelegate act = () => sut.Handle(new Request { Id = default(Guid)});

    /// Assert 
    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(act);
    repositoryMock.Verify(repo => repo.Save(It.IsAny<Entity>(), Times.Never);
}
```

Reference [Assert.ThrowsAsync](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.ThrowsAsync)